# Kubernetes ConfigMap size limitation

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Though `resourceQuotas` may limit the number of configmaps in a namespace, is there any such option to limit the size of the individual configmap?
I will not like some user to start uploading large text files as configmaps.

What is the max size of ConfigMap etcd support? If there is a reasonable limit on the etcd side, should be fine then.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are no [hard-limits](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19969) on either the ConfigMap or Secret objects as of this writing.

There's, however, a 1MB limit from the [etcd](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19781) side which is where Kubernetes stores its objects.

From the API side, if you actually see the API [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/core/v1/types.go#L5027) and the ConfigMap type, you'll see that its [data](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/core/v1/types.go#L5040) field is Golang map of strings so this appears memory bound and managed at runtime unless somewhere else it gets defined with `make()`. Technically the max size for the number of keys on hashmap is the map length which is an `int` and the max value is explained here: [Maximum number of elements in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600763/maximum-number-of-elements-in-map). That would also be the theoretical limit for the value of data as the maximum value for `len(string)`.

If you actually want to get more insights from the API side where the kube-apiserver receives protobufs (or JSON for that matter) you can take a look at the [google protobuf maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128872/google-protobuf-maximum-size). That will give you some measure as to the limitation of sending the `data` field through the wire. There may be other limitation from the kube-apiserver itself when it comes to processing any large message.

Comment: Reading this: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1413 suggests there's a limit of 1mb

Comment: Yeah, there's a 1MB limitation from the etcd side, added more details. Thx!

Comment: thanks , 1 MB limit seems pretty reasonbale , i am thinking of some custom addmission controller to reject a config map request of size larger than X

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan no need to as at least from kubectl 1.18, you get an error if cm is larger than 1 MB

Answer (score 5):

The size of the individual configmap is limited to 1mb, according to kubernetes.io:

> A ConfigMap is not designed to hold large chunks of data. The data stored in a ConfigMap cannot exceed 1 MiB. If you need to store settings that are larger than this limit, you may want to consider mounting a volume or use a separate database or file service.

The quote is taken from here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#motivation

Answer (score -2):

Till date config maps come under object count quota. You can enforce a maximum on number of configmaps. You cant put limits on size of individual config map. As they are not yet included under Storage Resource Quota.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/

Comment: I believe his question is about the limit on the ConfigMap size itself not on the number of ConfigMaps you can have on a cluster

Comment: yes @Rico i have mentioned you cant put limits on size of a configmap. I will edit it if it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks , for the size limit I can do maybe custom admission controller for configmap

Comment: Cool.Let us know how you do it.