# How to import custom dashboards to grafana using helm

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I'm trying to understand helm and I wonder if someone could ELI5 to me something or help me with something.

So i did run below:

```
helm repo add coreos https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/coreos-charts/stable/
```

Then I installed kube-prometheus by using below:

```
helm install coreos/kube-prometheus --name kube-prometheus -f values.yaml --namespace monitoringtest
```

Everything works fine but I'm trying to add some custom dashboards from json files and I'm struggling to understand how to do it.

I was following this: `https://blogcodevalue.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/automate-grafana-dashboard-import-process/`

In my values.yaml I added below

```
serverDashboardConfigmaps:
  - example-dashboards
```

I understand that if I do:

```
helm upgrade --install kube-prometheus -f values.yaml --namespace monitoringtest coreos/kube-prometheus
```

That should cause grafana to pickup a below configmap called `example-dashboards` and load *.json files from `custom-dashboards` folder.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-dashboards
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "custom-dashboards/*.json").AsConfig | indent 2 }}

# Or
# 
# data:
#   custom-dashboard.json: |-
# {{ (.Files.Get "custom.json") | indent 4 }}
#
# The filename (and consequently the key under data) must be in the format `xxx-dashboard.json` or `xxx-datasource.json`
# for them to be picked up.
```

Now two questions:

How do I add above configmap to this helm release?

Where is this `custom-dashboards` folder located? Is it on my laptop and then is send to grafana?

Do I need to copy all of `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/coreos-charts/stable/` onto my laptop?

Sorry for explaining everything but I'm just trying to understand this.

Comment: I also faced that once upon a time. They use grafana-watcher sidecar which uploads dashboards and datasources into Grafana on startup. Actually, the way it does it is very prone to errors and i found it impossible to use on daily basis. I don't recommend you to go that route. What I do is use Grafana Provisioning: https://grafana.com/docs/administration/provisioning. So I simply mount dashboards into Grafana to /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/ directory. One downside of it is that you cannot anymore save dashboards in Grafana UI - only export as JSON and upload to Git.

Comment: Thanks but i don't think I can do that using helm?

Comment: Why not, you can modify Helm chart to do it. I also did it, but there were many modifications to original Helm chart. May be I can share some days later...

Comment: I think this is for now beyond my helm skills.

Comment: is it possible to link dashboards as URL? 
This example seems to show it:
https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/README.md#import-dashboards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest version of `kube-prometheus-stack` chart in 2021, According to [this answer on github](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/336#issuecomment-745569146), You should just create a configmap with dashboard data and right labels and it will be checked by sidecar in grafana pod.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-dashboards-custom-1
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
     grafana_dashboard: "1"
     prometheus: my-value
     release: prometheus

data:
  app-status.json: |-
    {
    "annotations": {
        "list": [
        {
```

`prometheus: my-value` comes from this helm chart value:

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    serviceMonitorSelector:
      matchLabels:
        prometheus: my-value
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find a good example of how to do this in the charts for prometheus-operator here:

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator/templates/grafana

It is a ConfigMapList that gets all JSONs from a given directory and stores them into ConfigMaps which are read by Grafana.

```
{{- $files := .Files.Glob "dashboards/*.json" }}
{{- if $files }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMapList
items:
{{- range $path, $fileContents := $files }}
{{- $dashboardName := regexReplaceAll "(^.*/)(.*)\\.json$" $path "${2}" }}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: {{ printf "%s-%s" (include "prometheus-operator.fullname" $) $dashboardName | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
    namespace: {{ template "prometheus-operator.namespace" . }}
    labels:
      {{- if $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.label }}
      {{ $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.label }}: "1"
      {{- end }}
      app: {{ template "prometheus-operator.name" $ }}-grafana
{{ include "prometheus-operator.labels" $ | indent 6 }}
  data:
    {{ $dashboardName }}.json: {{ $.Files.Get $path | toJson }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Mind that the size of a ConfigMap might be limited:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015758/4252480

Answer (score 5):

I partially figured it out. I can load dashboards from a configmap. Not from separate json files yet but it'a progress.

For anyone interested I put this on my github page: https://github.com/tretos53/notes/blob/master/Grafana/Readme.MD

Comment: For people from the future:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: custom-dashboards
data:
  rpi-dashboard.json: |-
{{ .Files.Get "dashboards/rpi-dashboard.json" | indent 4}}
`
with the path being relative to your helm chart

Answer (score 2):

The current way (2023) is easy. The helm chart comes from artifacthub.io.

First put the dashboard json in a subdirectory. Here it's in dashboards/node-exporter.json for the standard node-exporter dash.

Then uncomment dashboardprovider in values.yaml

```
dashboardProviders:
  dashboardproviders.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    providers:
    - name: 'default'
      orgId: 1
      folder: ''
      type: file
      disableDeletion: false
      editable: true
      options:
        path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/default
```

Then add the file to "dashboards: default:"

```
dashboards:
  default:
    node-exporter-dashboard:
      file: dashboards/node-exporter.json
```

Then helm install or helm upgrade and grafana-dashboards-default ConfigMap pops up which can be selected in the interface. The configmap contains the full json in node-exporter-dashboard.json.

info found here: https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-upload-dashboards-as-json-files-to-kubernetes-via-helm/59731

Comment: Is there a link to docs for how to do this?

Comment: think i found it here. https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-upload-dashboards-as-json-files-to-kubernetes-via-helm/59731

Comment: Beauty, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do so. It also depends on the Grafana/Prometheus Stack Chart version. The info is here: https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana#import-dashboards
(Grafana chart can override `kube-prometheus-stack` values since the latter is dependent on Grafana)

The one that definitely worked for me is `Sidecar for dashboards`.
If you want to import dashboards for all Grafana organizations as well, you need to use `dashboardProviders: {}`
Some details: https://grafana.com/tutorials/provision-dashboards-and-data-sources/