# adding common-library files into a configmap, when used with libraries

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a common set of files that goes into configmap from `common/config-dir` and few chart specific config files in `appchart/config-dir`

I am following the documentation from [Helm.sh](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/)
for using library charts to merge common and chart specific data. I am specifying `{{ (.Files.Glob "config-dir/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}` right under `data` in both `common` library chart as well as `appchart`, However, library chart is not picking up the `config-dir` files from `common` chart.

Attaching `_configmap.yaml` from `common` library chart and `configmap.yaml` from application chart.

> _configmap.yaml

```
{{- define "common.configmap.tpl" -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name | printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name }}
data: 
{{ (.Files.Glob "config-dir/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "common.configmap" -}}
{{- include "common.util.merge" (append . "common.configmap.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
```

> configmap.yaml

```
{{- include "common.configmap" (list . "appchart.configmap") -}}

{{- define "appchart.configmap" -}}
data: 
{{ (.Files.Glob "config-dir/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that path don't match can you try deploying the chart with `--debug --dry-run`?

Comment: @Crou when I tried to debug, its picking up the files only from `appchart/config-dir` but not `common/config-dir/*`
Tried to give a  clear description here : https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8200

Answer (score -1):

Before getting into the problem, what is the size of those library files? There is a hard-limit of configmap not from kubernetes but from *etcd* of **1MB**. If the files per configmap are greater than 1MB you should be using volumes for that purpose.

Please check configmap hard-limits. [Kubernetes ConfigMap size limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012798/kubernetes-configmap-size-limitation)

Next can you run the helm install command with --debug and --dry-run flag and paste the output.

Next step can be to further go into the granularity separate the subchart and try using the same template and check it.

Comment: my config files are no larger than 10kb