# Kubernetes: What is the maximum value of env's count in pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Kubernetes: What is the maximum value of env's count in pod?
I found a option in pod.Spec 'enableServiceLinks' which default true, but the pod has more envs when enableServiceLinks=true. So I set it to false, things get better. I want to know, how much envs can exist in a pod?

Comment: can you please add more information and clarify the question. To be honest i didnt understood in the end what exactly you want: max size of one env or total count? I feel this is about total count, but  better to double check. also provide pods yaml and what you have for now

Comment: provide example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limits for env's count in pod. You are not limited by count/numbet/etc - you are limited by memory itself.

What you have in any linux os, is [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). There are no shortcuts for different sections, your one is **Limits on size of arguments and environment**

> **Most UNIX implementations impose some limit on the total size of the
> command-line argument (argv) and environment (envp) strings that may
> be passed to a new program.** POSIX.1 allows an implementation to
> advertise this limit using the **ARG_MAX constant** (either defined in
> <limits.h> or available at run time using the call
> sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)). **On Linux prior to kernel 2.6.23, the memory
> used to store the environment and argument strings was limited to 32
> pages (defined by the kernel constant MAX_ARG_PAGES). On architectures
> with a 4-kB page size, this yields a maximum size of 128 kB.**
>
> **On kernel 2.6.23 and later, most architectures support a size limit
> derived from the soft RLIMIT_STACK resource limit** (see getrlimit(2))
> that is in force at the time of the execve() call. (Architectures with
> no memory management unit are excepted: they maintain the limit that
> was in effect before kernel 2.6.23.) This change allows programs to
> have a much larger argument and/or environment list. For these
> architectures, the total size is limited to 1/4 of the allowed stack
> size. (Imposing the 1/4-limit ensures that the new program always has
> some stack space.) Since Linux 2.6.25, the kernel places a floor of 32
> pages on this size limit, so that, even when RLIMIT_STACK is set very
> low, applications are guaranteed to have at least as much argument and
> environment space as was provided by Linux 2.6.23 and earlier. (This
> guarantee was not provided in Linux 2.6.23 and 2.6.24.) Additionally,
> the limit per string is 32 pages (the kernel constant MAX_ARG_STRLEN),
> and the maximum number of strings is 0x7FFFFFFF.

So, in 2 words,

- On Linux prior to kernel 2.6.23: maximum size of 128 kB
- On kernel 2.6.23 and later: most architectures support a size limit derived from the soft `RLIMIT_STACK` resource

What I also think - there is a limit in 1MB of etcd(this is a place where kubernetes keeps all objects). So in case you use configmaps - you have to remember about this limitation. Limit 1MB is etcd limit itself.

Urls to check:

1. [Size limit for ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19781)
2. @Rico answer on stack: [Kubernetes ConfigMap size limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015758/9929015)